# Building an App Builder - how do they do it?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile

The internet is full of solutions where someone with no coding experience can design an app, and then have it deployed to their phones via another app. So for example you can log on to appsheet, create all the parameters for an application, then download appsheet to your phone. from there, you log into your appsheet account, and download any of the apps you have created.Does anyone know how this is accomplished?

My use case is that I have an app that I would like to offer to Universities, but would like each universities' mobile application to be custom built for their needs. I have developed web, android and ios apps in the past, and have a Software Engineering background, so I am looking for the right methodology to accomplish something like this. Are there any specific frameworks or technologies you would advise me look at to accomplish this tasking? If you have any questions or concerns for me, please do not hesitate to ask!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work at AppSheet. There are two basic approaches an app builder can follow: (a) act as a code generator, or (b) implement an intepreter. In the former case, it spits out code that gets compiled into an executable package that can be installed and run on a device. In the latter case, the "app" you define is meta-data in a higher-level definition that is interpreted in a host wrapper app. Each has its strengths and weaknesses. AppSheet uses the latter approach.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that they just have one universal, configurable app which they configure for your specific needs by generating a config file or something like that, and then packaging it all up into an apk.

Comment: That is what I am thinking. You download the master application, log-in, and access your designed app's configuration file. But then, somehow: 
1. That configuration file is downloaded - easy enough via any RESTful service
2. The app then parses the config file, and depending on its contents, creates an APK or IPA file. 
3. The app installs that APK or IPA file on the clients machine. 

Steps 2 - 3 I am struggling with understanding how they are accomplished.

Comment: It's more like an APK should be created on the server, and then you download it and do whatever you want, like install it to your device or publish it to Google Play. I'd package the config file into the resulting app, so it parses it on startup and configures itself. Just to clarify: the code inside is the same for all of the generated apps.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is great but that is not possible. We cannot imagine every scenario to build such app. We have to imagine for each scenario and have to code for such scenarios.

Comment: You may be misunderstanding the question if you think it is impossible. I am essentially describing a DIY (do it yourself) app creator, and how that app creator is, in itself, created. There are tons of them out there.